# A piecewise function inserted into an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f : \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nice function, and let's say we define a function $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{R}$ as:

$g(x,t) := f(x,t)$ for $x \geq 0$ and $t>0$

$g(x,t) := f(-x,t)$ for $x \leq 0$ and $t>0$

Now assume that $x<t$. In this case, how would you simplify the following integral?

$\int\limits_{0}^{t} \left[ \int\limits_{x-t+\eta}^{x+t-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right] d\eta$

I know that $g(-x,t) = g(x,t)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $x<t$, this means that $x-t<0$. Would this mean that:

$\int\limits_{0}^{t} \left[ \int\limits_{x-t+\eta}^{x+t-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right] d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t} \left[ \int\limits_{x-t+\eta}^{0} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi + \int\limits_{0}^{x+t-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right] d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t} \left[ \int\limits_{-(t-x-\eta)}^{0} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi + \int\limits_{0}^{t + x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right] d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t} \left[ \int\limits_{0}^{t-x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi + \int\limits_{0}^{t + x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi \right] d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits_{0}^{t-x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \int\limits_{0}^{t + x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks ok,

you can also continue with substitution
$u=\xi\pm x-\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits_{0}^{t-x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \int\limits_{0}^{t + x-\eta} g(\xi,\eta) d\xi d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits_{\eta+x}^{t} g(\xi-x-\eta,\eta) d\xi d\eta + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \int\limits_{ \eta-x}^{t } g(\xi+ x-\eta,\eta) d\xi d\eta$

$= -\int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits^{\eta+x}_{t} g(\xi-x-\eta,\eta) d\xi d\eta + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \int\limits_{ \eta-x}^{t } g(\xi+ x-\eta,\eta) d\xi d\eta$

$= \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits^{\eta+x}_{\eta-x} g(\xi+ x-\eta,\eta)-g(\xi-x-\eta,\eta) d\xi d\eta$